# Vaadin flow, trying to display Horizontal layout in Grid

Tags: vaadin

I have written below code, where I want to add HorizontalLayout with TextBox and Button in Vaadin Grid. But when I run the code it is showing the output as

com.vaadin.flow.component.orderedlayout.HorizontalLayout@145a03ea
com.vaadin.flow.component.orderedlayout.HorizontalLayout@1f7acb46

```
package com.packagename.myapp;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.vaadin.flow.component.Text;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.button.Button;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.grid.Grid;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.orderedlayout.HorizontalLayout;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.orderedlayout.VerticalLayout;
import com.vaadin.flow.router.Route;

@Route("table")
public class TestTable extends VerticalLayout {
    private Grid<TblValue> grid = new Grid<>();
    public TestTable() {
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        grid.addColumn(TblValue::getLayout);
        grid.setItems(createData());
        add(grid);
    }

    private List<TblValue> createData(){
        List<TblValue> data = new ArrayList<>();
        data.add(new TblValue());
        data.add(new TblValue());
        return data;
    }

    private class TblValue {
        HorizontalLayout layout = new HorizontalLayout();
        private Text txt = new Text("test string");
        private Button btn = new Button("Submit");
        public TblValue() {
            layout.add(txt, btn);
        }
        public HorizontalLayout getLayout() {
            return layout;
        }
        public void setLayout(HorizontalLayout layout) {
            this.layout = layout;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably want to use addComponentColumn(..) instead of addColumn(..).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments by Tatu Lund, the solution to your problem is to use `grid.addComponentColumn(...)` instead of `grid.addColumn(...)`.

The `addColumn(...)` method will always show a String. If the valueprovider returns any Object, it will show its string value with `String.valueOf(object)`.  This is what you are seeing. `com.vaadin.flow.component.orderedlayout.HorizontalLayout@145a03ea` is what you get when you call `String.valueOf(myHorizontalLayout)`.

`addComponentColumn(...)` on the other hand will take the returned HorizontalLayout of the valueProvider, and put the actual component into the cell which is what you wanted.